# Unknown Error while using Javascript promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, ecmascript-5

I am new to Javascript and trying to understand how promises work. I have written the below code to call a REST API and resolve the response.

```
const buyFlightTicket = () => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout( () => {
            let commentResponse = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1'); 
            commentResponse
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        resolve(response.json());
                    } else {
                        reject("Failed to fetch comment: " + response.statusText);
                    }
                })
                .reject("Failed to fetch comment");
        }, 3000);
    })
}

buyFlightTicket()
.then( (responseData) => console.log(responseData))
.catch( (error) => console.log(error));
```

I am able to log the response data but I am getting Error: Unknown error just before the response is being logged to the console.

What is causing this error?

**Also, how do i rewrite this code using callbacks without using Promise?**

Comment: I think you must use .catch("Failed to fetch comment") instead of .reject("Failed to fetch comment").

Comment: @soltex Thanks. I figured this out after i posted.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! Immediately `resolve` after the `setTimeout`, and put the rest in a `then` callback.

Comment: "*how do i rewrite this code using callbacks without using Promise?*" - why would you want to do that? Also, it's impossible, since `fetch` returns a promise you'll have to use.

Comment: @Bergi Without the anti-pattern, can you please tell me how I would re-write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `catch`, not `.reject`

```
            commentResponse
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        resolve(response.json());
                    } else {
                        reject("Failed to fetch comment: " + response.statusText);
                    }
                })
                .catch(() => "Failed to fetch comment");
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: Can you help me with how to re-write this same logic without the use of promises? How can i achieve this with callbacks in ES5?

Comment: Yes, you can use fetch, which also return a promise. I add it in the another answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use fetch, which also return a promise

```
const buyFlightTicket = () => {
    let commentResponse = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1'); 
    return commentResponse
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                return (response.json());
            } else {
                return new Error("Failed to fetch comment: " + response.statusText);
            }
        })
}

buyFlightTicket()
.then( (responseData) => console.log(responseData))
.catch( (error) => console.log(error));
```

If the browser doesn't support the `Promise`, you can add the `polyfill`  or you can use the xhr

```
    var buyFlightTicket = function(cb, errorCb) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4){
                if (xhr.status === 200){
                  cb(xhr.responseText)
                } else {
                  errorCb(xhr.statusText);
                }
            }
        };


        xhr.send(null);
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            console.error(xhr.statusText);
        };
        console.log('end')
    }
    buyFlightTicket(successCb, errorCb)
    function successCb(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
    function errorCb(err) { console.log(err) }
```